# ImageView image not resizing with ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, tablelayout, scaletype

I have a TableLayout with cells of `ImageView`s. What I am trying to do is create a zooming effect by incrementing the size of the `ImageView`s in the tabel. This works perfectly for zooming out( the picture resizes with the `ImageView`) but, the problem is with zooming in. The picture does not resize when the `ImageView` is made bigger.

Here is an example:
[image]

I want the image to be the same size as the ImageView(each black square is an ImageView)

Here is my code for the zooming ( any tips on better implementation would be appreciated, don't want to use pinch zoom ).

```
zoomIndex ranges from -2, 2. (only allow them to zoom twice in each direction)
zoomInThreshold = 2, zoomOutThreshold = -2. 
defaultSize = 50, zoomIncrement = 15;


                if(zoomIndex < zoomInThreshold)
                    defaultSize += zoomIncrement;


                for(int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); ++i)
                {
                    TableRow row = (TableRow)table.getChildAt(i);
                    for(int r = 0; r < row.getChildCount(); ++r)
                    {
                        ImageView img = (ImageView)row.getChildAt(r);

                        if(zoomIndex  < zoomInThreshold)
                        {
                            TableRow.LayoutParams imgLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                    defaultSize,
                                    defaultSize
                            );
                            img.setLayoutParams(imgLayoutParams);

                            if(img.getDrawable() != null)
                            {
                                img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                                img.setMaxHeight(defaultSize);
                                img.setMaxWidth(defaultSize);
                                img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(zoomIndex < zoomInThreshold)
                    zoomIndex++;
```

Comment: you should offer bounty for this :)

Comment: I can only start a bounty in 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, this problem only happens when I load my drawings from the xml files. All I had to do was add this line when loading the drawing

```
img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

This is how it fits in:

```
                if(drawableID != -1)
                {
                    Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableID);
                    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pic, 50, 50, true);
                    im.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                    ic.setImage(im);

                    im.setTag(ic);

                    im.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

                    //rotate the icon
                    im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.set(im.getImageMatrix());
                    matrix.postRotate(rotAngle, pic.getWidth() / 2, pic.getHeight() / 2);
                    im.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                    im.setOnLongClickListener(longListen);//only set this listener if there is something there
                }
```

I only had `img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);` in my zoom buttons press.